# C# Static Class and Static Constructor for API system?

Tags: c#, class, constructor, static, expansion

Before we go any farther into the question, let me explain the situation.
I am developing an API system for Unity Game engine, now, the engine gives an attribute that is called automatically the moment you add the dll into the game engine, so, I am trying to use that call to make some folder structures inside the game engine, so far so good but,...
now take a look at this snippet :

```
[InitializeOnLoad]
public static class FolderConstruction
{
    static FolderConstruction()
    {
        // Assets/Buzz
        if (!AssetDatabase.IsValidFolder(Resource.ASSETS_FOLDER + "/" + Resource.COMPANY_NAME))
            AssetDatabase.CreateFolder(Resource.ASSETS_FOLDER, Resource.COMPANY_NAME);
    }
}
```

As you can see, I am utilizing the static constructor for this. I am well aware of partial methods but here is the problem about them, the user of this API can only declare that partial method once. now, lets think about a visual studio solution that the user may have. in this solution, he is making three different dll files and each one of those projects will reference my API. see the problem? what if he wants to call upon this static class to add more folders to the structure separately per dll? this is why the partial method system won't work for me.

In other words, is there any option to expand upon a static class with static construct beside the partial method solution?

Is there any way to handle this or should I totally forget about this possibility in my API?

please help.

Comment: So, you want to write code for the same static class in multiple dlls?

Comment: So you want to force the user of your API to implement some initialization-logic, where you only define the logic interface, but not its implementation?

Comment: I don't want to force any user to do anything, I want to give them opportunity to utilize this if they want to.

Comment: and yes, I want to write code for the same static class and same constructor in multiple dll files